# PL/pgSQL function not returning expected value

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I have written a trigger function in plpgsql which is actioned `AFTER INSERT` on a table.

The trigger function calls two other functions and the first one does not return the correct value. I am at my wit's end with this and searching has not turned up any answers.

Cam anyone shed any light on the problem, please?

The trigger function below:

```
CREATE TRIGGER timetotaketrigger
  AFTER INSERT
  ON "Prescription Schema"."TimeToTake"
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE failtimetotakeinsert();
```

The above trigger is working as expected.

The failtimetotakeinsert is being called with the source being :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION failtimetotakeinsert()
RETURNS trigger AS '
DECLARE

    -- declare variables to hold the information from
    -- the row being inserted
    -- and save the data from the new row
    drug_name character(32);
    drug_strength character(8);
    drug_strength_unit character(16);
    drug_dosage integer;

    row_counts integer = 0;
    frequency integer = 0;
    difference integer = 0;

 BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE ''Frequency at the start is %'',frequency;
    -- save the data from the new row
    drug_name = NEW."DrugName";
    drug_strength = NEW."DrugStrength";
    drug_strength_unit = NEW."DrugStrengthUnit";
    drug_dosage = NEW."DrugDosage";

    -- get the frequency 
    SELECT INTO frequency GetPrescriptionFrequency(drug_name,
                                    drug_strength,
                                    drug_strength_unit,
                                    drug_dosage);

RAISE NOTICE ''frequency is %'',frequency;        
    -- count the rows from the current table
    SELECT INTO row_counts CountTimeToTake(drug_name,drug_strength,
                                           drug_strength_unit,drug_dosage);
RAISE NOTICE ''row counts are %'',row_counts;

    -- work out the difference
    difference = row_counts - frequency;
RAISE NOTICE ''Difference is %'',difference;
    -- now check the two figures
    IF difference > 0 THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION ''More rows than frequency requires'';
    END IF;

    RETURN NULL;
 END;
'  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

The problem I am having is with the first function that is called within this one because it is not returning a value yet when called from PgAdmin sql environemtn the result is as I expect.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetPrescriptionFrequency
    (character, character, character, integer)
RETURNS integer AS '
#variable_conflict error
DECLARE
   -- Declare drug_name,
   --         drug_strength,
   --         drug_strength_unit and
   --         drug_dosage as an alias for the argument variables
   -- normally referenced with the $1,$2,$3 and $4 identifiers

   drug_name ALIAS FOR $1;
   drug_strength ALIAS FOR $2;
   drug_strength_unit ALIAS FOR $3;
   drug_dosage ALIAS FOR $4;

   -- declare a variable to hold the count

   freq integer := 0;

BEGIN

  SELECT INTO freq COUNT(*) 
      FROM "Prescription Schema"."PrescriptionItem" 
      WHERE "PrescriptionItem"."DrugName" = drug_name AND
            "PrescriptionItem"."DrugStrength" = drug_strength AND
            "PrescriptionItem"."DrugStrengthUnit" = drug_strength_unit AND
            "PrescriptionItem"."DrugDosage" = drug_dosage;
--       IF NOT FOUND THEN
--          RAISE EXCEPTION ''prescription item not found %'', drug_strength;
--       END IF;
   IF freq IS NULL THEN 
     RETURN 0;
   ELSE
     RETURN freq;
   END IF;
END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

The other function is behaving correctly but I have included the source as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CountTimeToTake(character,character,character,integer)
    RETURNS integer AS '
DECLARE
   -- Declare drug_name,
   --         drug_strength,
   --         drug_strength_unit and
   --         drug_dosage as an alias for the argument variables
   -- normally referenced with the $1,$2,$3 and $4 identifiers

   drug_name ALIAS FOR $1;
   drug_strength ALIAS FOR $2;
   drug_strength_unit ALIAS FOR $3;
   drug_dosage ALIAS FOR $4;
   -- declare a variable to hold the count
   row_count integer := 0;
BEGIN

-- count the number of TimeToTake rows for the given
-- parameter values

   SELECT INTO row_count COUNT(*) FROM "Prescription Schema"."TimeToTake"
          WHERE "TimeToTake"."DrugName" = drug_name AND
                "TimeToTake"."DrugStrength" = drug_strength AND
                "TimeToTake"."DrugStrengthUnit" = drug_strength_unit AND
                "TimeToTake"."DrugDosage" = drug_dosage;

   return row_count;
END;
' LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

I have tried everything I can find on the Internet and also amongst you previous questions to no avail. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

### Trigger

Simplified and rewritten:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION failtimetotakeinsert()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN

IF GetPrescriptionFrequency(NEW."DrugName", NEW."DrugStrength"
                           ,NEW."DrugStrengthUnit", NEW."DrugDosage") 
          > CountTimeToTake(NEW."DrugName",NEW."DrugStrength"
                           ,NEW."DrugStrengthUnit",NEW."DrugDosage") THEN
   RAISE EXCEPTION 'More rows than frequency requires';
END IF;

RETURN NULL;

END
$func$   LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- It's good practice to dollar-quote the function body to avoid quoting-problems.
- `plpgsql` is a keyword in `LANGUAGE plpgsql` and does not have to be quoted.
- Don't *ever* use the silly ancient type `character(n)` unless you positively have to. It operates with blank-padded strings and truncates strings and rarely does anything useful. It's only there for historical reasons and standard compliance.
  Just use `text` (practically the same as `varchar`), or if you really need to enforce a maximum length at type level, use `varchar(n)`. I use just `text` 99%. Be sure to read [the manual about character types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html).
  `
- The assignment operator in plpgsql is `:=`. The SQL-style `=` works, too, ATM but is undocumented and may go away without warning.
- Removed pointless `RAISE NOTICE 'Frequency at start is %', frequency;` - always `0`.
- Radically simplify.
- If the function `CountTimeToTake()` should be defined with camel case, you'd need to enclose it in double quotes. But from what I see, it isn't.

### Function

Repaired, simplified and rewritten:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetPrescriptionFrequency
    (_drug_name text, _drug_strength text, _drug_strength_unit text
                                         , _drug_dosage integer)
  RETURNS integer LANGUAGE sql AS 
$func$
SELECT count(*)::int
FROM  "Prescription Schema"."PrescriptionItem" p
WHERE  p."DrugName"         = _drug_name
AND    p."DrugStrength"     = _drug_strength
AND    p."DrugStrengthUnit" = _drug_strength_unit
AND    p."DrugDosage"       = _drug_dosage;
$func$
```

#### Major points

- Use parameter names instead of `ALIAS` in PostgreSQL 9.1:
- **!** The use of the **data type `character`** is plain wrong here and probably your key problem. 
  `character` is a synonym  for `character(1)` and truncates the string to the first character.
- In queries inside a plpgsql function, variables and parameters are visible and will take precedence over column names. This can lead to unexpected results. You have to table-qualify column names in this case to make them unambiguous.
  It's good practice to use parameter and variable names that will not conflict with column names to begin with. I made it a habit to use the `_` prefix, which I never use for column names, but anything works, as long as you avoid naming conflicts.
- I would advice not to use camel case with PostgreSQL identifiers. Use lower case exclusively and save yourself a lot of double-quoting and confusion.
- `count()` never returns `NULL`, you don't need to provide for this case. I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html):

> It should be noted that except for count, these functions return a
>   null value when no rows are selected.

- `count()` returns `bigint`, so cast to `integer` in this scenario.
- For this simple case, a [`LANGUAGE sql` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html) probably does a better job.
- Fix up your other function `CountTimeToTake()` accordingly.

Comment: @Erwin_Brandstetter - thank you for your suggestions. I didn't know about sql functions before. Where can I read up about these and the changes to plpgsql from the syntax version I was trying to use.

Comment: @user1613784: You could start in the PostgreSQL manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/xfunc-sql.html). I wrote some more (and added links) about `plpgsql` vs. `sql` functions in [this related answer at dba.SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684).